# How can I browse or search the iOS app store from my desktop?

Tags: ios-appstore

Now that iTunes no longer lists apps in the iTunes store, the only way I can find to browse or search the iOS app store is on an iOS device itself. This is rather inconvenient when, say, I'm trying to do research on which of several related apps to get - or even if I just want to look up info on an app while I'm at my computer and my iPad isn't nearby.

Is there any official way to browse iOS apps from a desktop computer?

Answer (score 5):

I couldn't find an Apple site where you can search the iTunes store online.

That said, many other features are available online from Apple, and there are third-party search options.

You can access top charts and featured stuff here: `https://www.apple.com/itunes/charts/` (Trying to click the `Shop the iTunes Store now` button on that page just opens iTunes, which can't access the iOS App Store anymore.)

I accidentally stumbled upon this page with the Categories, so you can browse apps by category alphabetically or by what's popular: `https://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/ios/id36?mt=8`. This looks like an old page, and the interface isn't great.

Some unofficial search workarounds might be Googling the app name and adding `site:itunes.apple.com/us/app/` to your query, or using `http://appshopper.com/`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

Apple have very quietly [released iTunes 12.6.3](https://www.macrumors.com/2017/10/09/apple-itunes-with-app-store-included/) - compatible with iOS 11 & still containing the App Store.

[Apple KB: Deploy apps in a business environment with iTunes](https://support.apple.com/HT208079)

You need the direct link, it apparently does not appear as an update.
[Mac link.](https://secure-appldnld.apple.com/itunes12/091-33628-20170922-EF8F0FE4-9FEF-11E7-B113-91CF9A97A551/iTunes12.6.3.dmg)
[Windows 32 bit link.](https://secure-appldnld.apple.com/itunes12/091-33627-20170922-EF8CB708-9FEF-11E7-8504-92CF9A97A551/iTunesSetup.exe)
[Windows 64-bit Link.](https://secure-appldnld.apple.com/itunes12/091-33626-20170922-F51D3530-A003-11E7-8324-03D19A97A551/iTunes64Setup.exe)

If you've already been using 12.7 you may have luck importing your 12.7 lib  to a clean 12.6.3 Library, as outlined on MacRumors, but I had no joy.

I ended up restoring a backup of my Library [just the catalog not all the tunes] from a time before i updated to 12.7.

Answer (score 4):

To supplement the other responses, some quick Googling led me to [fnd](https://fnd.io/), a website that lets you search the app store.  [Here](https://www.cultofmac.com/273180/handy-web-tool-much-faster-way-search-itunes-store/)'s a 2014 review of it on Cult of Mac, so it's been around and working for some time.

Comment: This was super helpful. It helped me find https://fnd.io/#/us/ios-universal-app/792750948-peloton-at-home-fitness-by-peloton-intera which then had a blue Free link in the top right to https://apps.apple.com/us/app/peloton-at-home-fitness/id792750948 which then showed the minimum iPadOS, which is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Happy to say fnd.io is still working in 2023. As an Aussie developer, I really appreciate being able to search the US store without playing games with trying to create a US account.

Answer (score 2):

Apple maintains public-facing webpages for all apps in the App Store at itunes.apple.com. If you use Google or an equivalent search engine and limit the results to that domain, you can effectively search the App Store from any web browser.

For example, if you search the itunes.apple.com domain for ["to do"](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=JjkNXKyYHqqJ5wLPopXACA&q=site%3Aitunes.apple.com%20to%20do&btnK=Google%20Search&oq=site%3Aitunes.apple.com%20to%20do&gs_l=psy-ab.3...415.3264..3404...1.0..0.91.1825.28......0....1..gws-wiz.....0..0j0i131j0i10._Nye6ly32j8), you'll get results for [Microsoft To-Do](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/microsoft-to-do/id1212616790?mt=8), [Wunderlist](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/wunderlist-to-do-list-tasks/id406644151?mt=8), [Do!](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi9k5KsjJPfAhURvlkKHUkPBXwQFjACegQIChAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fitunes.apple.com%2Fus%2Fapp%2Fdo-simple-to-do-list%2Fid421819675%3Fmt%3D8&usg=AOvVaw3EFi5TfytSWExt-SUJgMEf), etc. Click any of those links and you'll get effectively the same listing page as what you would get in the App Store app on iOS devices.

Comment: This approach may be limited by how Google indexes in other countries but it doesn't show results as well as fnd, eg https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aitunes.apple.com+fragment+shader. vs https://fnd.io/#/us/search?mediaType=all&term=fragment%20shader

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Apple is trying to hide their AppStore from being searched through a web browser, however I found a link that seems to work.  While you can't browse categories like before, at least you can search for specific apps.

https://www.apple.com/us/search

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).